# Is there a way to get this code to multiply integer by 2?

Tags: python

def main():

```
print ('Please Enter an integer')

print ("")

integer = input()    

print ('you have entered ' + integer)

print ('Twice of that number is ' + integer * 2)
```

i need the input to multiply by 2, but when i run it, the final line says "twice of that number is 4242" when i input 42 as the integer, instead of 84

Comment: You need to convert your integer into a string to print it. So like so:  ``` print ('Twice of that number is ' + str(integer * 2)) ```  python doesn't allow for concatenating of integers and strings

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly: you forgot the first half: `input` returns a string. As OP found out, you can't multiply a string with a number and expect a correct mathematical output. (There are no 2 digits `a` and `b` so that `str(a)+str(b) == str(a+b)` in decimal.)

Comment: Simply convert it to an int then:  print ('Twice of that number is ' + str(int("2") * 2)